# asynchronous filter function for ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, angular6, ng2-smart-table

I'm working on an Angular 6 app.
I have a custom component in a `ng2-smart-table` that displays properly. I would like to filter them.
The call to the API is done asynchronously and returns a **promise**.
The `filterFunction` parameter doesn't filter my table at all.

```
settings = {
    actions: {
      ...
    },
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'Id'
      },
      organisation_id: {
        title: 'Cumstom Field',
        type: 'custom',
        renderComponent: CustomComponent,
        filterFunction: (cell?: any, search?: string) => {
           return this.api-service-filter(cell, search)
         },
```

`api-service-filter` returns a Promise.
When I log the results in the console I get the proper `true` / `false` returns from the API. But it doesn't change the display at all.

Any idea of how I could make this work ? Is it a feature of ng2-smart-table or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround for this, created a local copy of the API response and subscribed to this API call.
The filter function then only access the local copy and can be written synchronously.